# Django 2. Обращение к поля БД

Tags: django, django-orm

Есть 3 модельки.

```
    class Autor(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Book(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Genre(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        autor = models.ForeignKey('Autor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Есть такой тест:

```
assert response_data[1]['name'] == 'Horor'
assert response_data[1]['book'] == 'first'
assert response_data[1]['autor'] == 'Vova'
assert response_data[1]['description'] == ''
```

Во views я делаю так:

```
class CategoryView(DetailView):
model = Autor
template_name = '_'
```

Я понял нужно как-то через get_context_data(). И как потом обращать в шаблоне к полям из разных таблиц?
Или нужно связывать таблице не по id, а по name?

Answer (score 0):

> как потом обращать в шаблоне к полям из разных таблиц?

В вашем вью переопределяете `get_context_data` и добавляете новый ключ в контекст:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):  
   data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
   data['books'] = Book.objects.all()
   return data
```

И этот ключ становится переменной в шаблоне:

```
{% for book in books %}
    <p>{{book.name}}<p>
{% end for %}
```

как видно из примера, через эту переменную можно обращаться к полям других таблиц